Ubuntu 24.04: how to add LPD printer
I am trying to install a driver to a LPD printer. I am on Ubuntu 24.04, and I found instructions for Ubuntu 22.04, but I am not able to adjust the 22.04 instructions for 24.04.
According to the documentation, I should click printer -> Additional printer settings -> then find some "Network Printer" menu where I could choose LPD/LPR. But I don't see how to access the Additional printer settings button in Ubuntu 24.04 (which used to be at the very bottom)? I can only access the Add printer button on the top, but this only lists available printer found on the network and has no LPD/LPR option?
Thanks!
Left are the 22.04 instructions and right what I get on 24.04:
 

they seem to have removed the option on the GUI, must be a booboo.
sudo apt install cups
sudo lpadmin -p printername -E -v lpd://username@ipaddress/path -m everywhere

you may need to open the printer pake, go to printer details and add  ppd file associated with the printer

You can download "Printer Settings" from the App Center and you will get the same interface you are joining on your left screenshot, i.e. the option to add "LPD/LPR Host or Printer".
